# Android Studio Git Directory Best Practice

Tags: git, android-studio

I have an Android Studio project and wondering what the best practice is on setting up Git locally. What should the 'Git Repository Directory' be set to? Should it be set to the root of the project directory, a general projects folder, or another disk drive/network drive.
[image]

This is in on a home network and I'm the only person needing to access the code.

Answer (score 0):

It can be set up anywhere, it doesn't really matter.

The best practice would I would recommend is put your project on git-hub or bit-bucket as its more safer.
To do this go to version control(VCS) -> Import Into version Control -> Share on Github/Bitbucket -> ...Continue with future steps.